# Create column from symbol in mutate (tidy eval)

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

So I want to create a new column called `var` that has the text "testing" for all rows. I.e. the result should be like `mtcars$var <- "testing"`. I have tried different things such as `as_name`, `as_string`...

```
library(tidyverse)    
f <- function(df, hello = testing){


  df %>% 
    mutate(var = hello)
}

f(mtcars)
```

Comment: You can do it with `!!as_string(ensym(myvar))`. However in most cases it is recommended to avoid this pattern. Unquoted names should refer to existing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do:

```
f <- function(df, hello = testing){
  hello <- deparse(substitute(hello))
  df %>% 
    mutate(var =rlang::as_name(hello))
}

f(mtcars)
```

**However**, as pointed out by @Lionel Henry(see comments below):

> `deparse`  will not check for simple inputs and might return a character vector. Then as_name() will fail if a length > 1 vector, or do nothing otherwise since it's already a string
>
> as_name(substitute(hello)) does the same but checks the input is a simple symbol or string. It is more constrained than as_label()

It might therefore be better rewritten as:

```
f <- function(df, hello = testing){
  hello <- as_label(substitute(hello))
  df %>% 
    mutate(var = hello )
}
```

Or:

```
f <- function(df, hello = testing){
  hello <- rlang::as_name(substitute(hello))
  df %>% 
    mutate(var = hello)
}
```

Result:

```
mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     var
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 testing
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 testing
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 testing
```

Comment: `deparse()` will not check for simple inputs and might return a character vector. Then `as_name()` will fail if a length > 1 vector, or do nothing otherwise since it's already a string. I would recommend `as_label(substitute(hello))`, which always returns a single string, no matter how complex the expression.

Comment: Thanks, will edit to add to the post. I had not yet met situations like this so it's awesome to learn about such cases.

Comment: For completeness, `as_name(substitute(hello))` does the same but checks the input is a simple symbol or string. It is more constrained than `as_label()`.

Comment: @NelsonGon: why not just like the first comment Lionel Henry made i.e. ``!!as_string(ensym(myvar))``?

Comment: @David I think there are possibilities. It also works. I am not (yet) an advanced `rlang` user. Lionel happens to author `rlang` and therefore has more authority to know what would work best.

Comment: @David I found this note in the docs: **as_string() is a well defined operation that guarantees the roundtrip symbol -> string -> symbol.**

Comment: @NelsonGon: Just a question: So is unquoting the same as evaluating according to your understanding?

Comment: @David Yes, take a look at this section which although it is on Quasiquotation(with a bias towards rlang), does cover this aspect. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html